# Override BinaryReader's ReadInt64?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I am not sure I am asking the right question here but I am wanting to be able to manipulate the code of ReadInt64 because of an endian experiment I am doing. The current code is this:

```
public virtual long ReadInt64() 
{
    FillBuffer(8);
    uint lo = (uint)(m_buffer[0] | m_buffer[1] << 8 |
                     m_buffer[2] << 16 | m_buffer[3] << 24);
    uint hi = (uint)(m_buffer[4] | m_buffer[5] << 8 |
                     m_buffer[6] << 16 | m_buffer[7] << 24);
    return (long) ((ulong)hi) << 32 | lo;
}
```

But what I want to do is flip the numbers my own way. I could do this by reading into a byte array but that hogs time and I would rather interact directly with m_buffer so that time is not wasted.

The problem is that I don't know where to start. Is it inheritance or overriding that I could do so that I could run my own ReadInt64 from an inherited binary reader? I don't know how to accomplish this and would like a nudge in the right direction.

And, yes, I am reading up on this subject but would love to hear if my thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ReadInt64` is marked with the `virtual` modifier, that is a hint to you that you can inherit and override it. Generally, you can [read the documentation for the class in question](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure it's not `sealed`, which would prevent you from inheriting it and see if the methods in question are virtual.

```
public class MyBinaryReader : BinaryReader
{
    public MyBinaryReader(Stream input) : base(input)
    {
    }

    public MyBinaryReader(Stream input, Encoding encoding) : base(input, encoding)
    {
    }

    public MyBinaryReader(Stream input, Encoding encoding, bool leaveOpen) : base(input, encoding, leaveOpen)
    {
    }

    public override long ReadInt64()
    {
        // Fill in your own custom logic here.
    }
}
```

And when you want to use it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Just a dummy stream, for the sake of the example.
    using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new MyBinaryReader(inputStream);
        long myValue = reader.ReadInt64();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my word. It's about to get real over here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I bet I could even make my own method like this and then just copy the code into it instead of overriding, right?

public long ReadInt64_MyWay()

Comment: @mirk I'm not sure what you mean by *make my own method like this*. Overriding `ReadInt64` *is your own method*, you implement it.

Comment: Right but instead of overriding at all, I could leave ReadInt64() alone, create a new function called ReadInt64_Custom() and just fill in the same code but with my own modifications. It achieves the same thing but both could be done, right? I should try this.

Comment: @mirk You can implement your own method and make `ReadInt64` call your method, if I understand what you mean correctly.